# C++Builder Clang std::less can't find overloaded operator<

Tags: c++, std, c++builder

The following program compiles fine using the classic C++Builder compiler, but fails using the Clang compiler:

```
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <tchar.h>
#else
  typedef char _TCHAR;
  #define _tmain main
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::complex<double> Complex;

bool operator<(const Complex & lhs, const Complex & rhs)
{
    return lhs.real() < rhs.real();
}

void doSort()
{
    std::vector<Complex> vc;
    std::sort(vc.begin(), vc.end());
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    doSort();
    return 0;
}
```

It also compiles and links with the classic compiler, but fails for the Clang compiler, if I add explicit less instance:

```
std::sort(vc.begin(), vc.end(), std::less<Complex>());
```

So far, I can only get the Clang compiler to compile if I write a function object:

```
template <typename T>
struct compLess
{
    bool operator()(const T & lhs, const T & rhs) const
    {
        return lhs < rhs;
    }
};

void doSort()
{
    std::vector<Complex> vc;
    std::sort(vc.begin(), vc.end(), compLess<Complex>());
}
```

Is this per the new C++ standard?  Is there something else I need to do to get std::less to recognize the operator< for Complex?

Thanks.

Comment: There isn't an operator< for std::complex<>.

Comment: There is a standalone operator< defined for complex<double> at about line 18 in the original listing.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see. Then I don't have an answer for you. (I suspect the problem that the non-member operator< is in the wrong namespace and isn't found via argument-dependent lookup, but I'm not sure. Putting it in the std namespace compiles on GCC but I don't know if that's legal.)

Answer (score 1):

All of the types and templates involved - `std::vector`, `std::complex`, `std::sort`, and `std::less` - are members of `namespace std`. There is nothing in [the ADL rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) that would cause a lookup in the global namespace, as that namespace is not involved. Especially not as the namespace std contains *lots* of `operator<` (just not the one needed here).

On the other hand it is not really a very good idea to overload comparisons for types that has no inherent order, like complex numbers. They are two-dimensional and not generally fit for a linear sort.

You "trick" (not really a trick) of using an explicit functor for the sort order is the correct way to handle this. So just do that.

Comment: It seems the namespace thing is correct, as wrapping the original function in a namespace std { } eliminates the problem.  Don't know if the lookup rules changed or if the original C++Builder compiler just threw in the global namespace for kicks.

Comment: The lookup rules haven't really changed, but older compilers didn't always get it right. Which here means looking in the wrong places (and make the program "work" when it shouldn't).